# iOS UICollectionView reloadData maps model to ViewCell incorrectly

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, reloaddata, uicollectionviewcell

If the model data in an `NSArray` does not change, and you call `reloadData` on the `UICollectionView`, do the cells appear in different spots?

I'm finding that if my `NSArray` holds Obj1, Obj2, Obj3, then at first, the `UICollectionView` correctly maps Obj1 to the first `collectionViewCell`, Obj2 to the second, etc. This is how it's set up in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, as it uses `indexPath.row` to get the right Obj from the array.

However, when I call `reloadData`, all the objects are mapped to the wrong UICollectionViewCell (Obj1 ends up somewhere else, such as the second `collectionViewCell`, and Obj2 ends up as the third `collectionViewCell`, etc.)

Why does this happen? I didn't find the reason in the documentation.

---

FURTHERMORE, I'm having the same problem when my model array does change. For example, if my `NSArray` is Obj1, Obj2, Obj3, and then new instances of the Objs are created and are now in a different order, such that the `NSArray` is Obj2, Obj3, Obj1... and then I call `reloadData`, I face the same problem.

Obj2 doesn't map to the first `UICollectionViewCell` as it should, but instead mapped to a different `UICollectionViewCell`

Anyone know why this happens with `UICollectionViews`?

Thanks!

EDIT: Code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
MIAppCell* cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MIAppCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
// set model data
[cell setAppTitle:[(MIAppDO*)[self.apps objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] getAppTitle]];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Show the code you're using for collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in this code. You might try logging indexPath and [(MIAppDO*)[self.apps objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] getAppTitle], and see if they're giving you something you don't expect.

Comment: I tried logging both already. They give what's expected, for the first cell, the indexPath.row is 0 and the getAppTitle comes from the first object (index 0) of the array. However, the UICollectionViewCell doesn't show the right title, it shows the title of another object elsewhere in the array.

Comment: I haven't seen this behavior before, so I'm at a loss to explain it. You might want to post the code in your custom cell.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of my custom cell, I figured out the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

Earlier, I was `dequeuing` a cell and setting it's new model data, but the model data wasn't correctly reflecting in the subclassed `UICollectionViewCell`.

I needed to override the setter methods for my properties that represent the model data for my subclassed `UICollectionViewCell`. In those overriden methods, I was able to update the appropriate views of the cell.